# purpose of Glib - g_io_channel_unix_new

Tags: c, gnome, glib

Could some one tell me what does this function do?

```
g_io_channel_unix_new
```

Gnome site has that It takes in a file descriptor as an argument and creates a channel. My question is what exactly does it do since i already have created the file/pipe (associated with fd)?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a file descriptor but want to use the GLib channel system instead, this is the function you use to get a channel from the file descriptor.